# Resizing multiple images and saving them to a separate folder

Tags: vb.net, image, resize, compression

I need to resize and compress 200 images that I have stored in a folder.
I am getting these images in a list using this code that I got from another question:

```
Dim dir = New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\Charbel\\Desktop\\Images")
Dim images = dir.GetFiles("*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList
Dim pictures As New List(Of PictureBox)
For Each img In images
    Dim picture As New PictureBox
    picture.Image = Image.FromFile(img.FullName)
    pictures.Add(picture)
Next
```

Now, I need to compress and reduce each image to (500x374) and then save them in another folder on my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let me first point out a couple of points about your code:

- PictureBox doesn't serve any purpose here. You shouldn't create a PictureBox to use the Image.
- Always remember to dispose the `Image` object (e.g., by wrapping it in a `Using` block) so you don't run into memory issues.
- Unlike C#, VB.NET doesn't require escaping the `\` character, therefore, you can write your path like this "C:\Users...".

Now, for resizing the image, you can simply create an instance of the [`Bitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?) class with the constructor that takes an image and a size argument: [`Bitmap(Image, Size)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_Drawing_Image_System_Drawing_Size_) or [`Bitmap(Image, Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_Drawing_Image_System_Int32_System_Int32_).

Here:

```
Dim sourcePath As String = "C:\Users\Charbel\Desktop\Images"
Dim outputPath As String = "C:\Users\Charbel\Desktop\Images\Resized"

IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath)

Dim dir = New IO.DirectoryInfo(sourcePath)
Dim files As IO.FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles("*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
For Each fInfo In files
    Using img As Bitmap = Image.FromFile(fInfo.FullName)
        Using resizedImg As New Bitmap(img, 500, 374)
            resizedImg.Save(IO.Path.Combine(outputPath, fInfo.Name),
                            Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End Using
    End Using
Next
```

Comment: Thanks.. it worked 
Can i rotate the image without using pictureBox?
all the examples on google are inside a pictureBox

Comment: Note that using `New Bitmap()`, you will lose both the original `PixelFormat` and the DPI resolution, which will set to the default, `Format32bppArgb` and (96:96) DPI.